# T-SQL - how to compare a SELECT resultset and IN list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, parameter-passing, case, conditional-statements

I have a query and in its WHERE clause I want to add an AND condition only if the resultset of one SELECT statement is IN a list of predefined values, otherwise the condition should not be added

```
SELECT 
    field1, field2, field3 ....
FROM 
    Table1 
JOIN 
    Table2 ON somekeymappings
WHERE 
    condition1 
    AND condition2 
    AND IF (SELECT ids from TABLE2) IN (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006)
        THEN condition3
GROUP BY 
    blah, blah, blah
HAVING 
    blah, blah
```

Comment: Asked second very similar question without accepting answer and not providing more details in previous question...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655012/t-sql-using-and-condition-only-if-a-value-from-a-list-is-present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 ....
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON somekeymappings
WHERE condition1 AND condition2 
AND (table2.id IN (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005,1006) AND condition3 
     OR table2.id NOT IN (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005,1006)) 
GROUP BY blah, blah, blah
HAVING blah, blah
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT field1, field2, field3 ....
    FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 on somekeymappings
    WHERE condition1 
          AND condition2 
          AND EXISTS (SELECT null from TABLE2 where id IN (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005,1006))
    THEN condition3
    GROUP BY blah, blah, blah
    HAVING blah, blah
```

Answer (score 0):

The IF...THEN operation you are describing can be expressed as a simple logic statement.

IF A THEN B
can also be expressed as
B OR NOT A

Therefore your statement would work as follows:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 ....
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 on somekeymappings
WHERE condition1 
      AND condition2 
      AND (condition3 
           OR Table2.Id NOT IN (1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005,1006)
          )
GROUP BY blah, blah, blah
HAVING blah, blah
```